# How a subprocess can notify the parent process when it finishes executing in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

sorry but I'm new to python. I needed my subprocess to notify the parent process that called him, but I can't block the parent for that.

I have something like that, but it's not what I need yet.

```
def signal_handling(signum, frame):
    sub.kill()
    sys.exit()


sub = subprocess.Popen(["python3.7", "test.py"])

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handling)
while True:
    sub.wait()
```

Comment: The parent process *always* receives a `SIGCHLD` when its subprocess exits. Hook that, and you don't need to trap anything else.

Comment: Hmm, I understand. I did the test here and it worked. Thank you very much.